# PrimeFaces primeDateRangeValidator - Get variable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need help with a problem i have using the primeDateRangeValidator.I need to get a variable (`private boolean validacionFechas;`) from this class and use it in another one. (Sorry for my bad english).

```
     @FacesValidator("primeDateRangeValidator")
public class PrimeDateRangeValidator implements Validator {
private boolean validacionFechas;
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }
         
        //Leave the null handling of startDate to required="true"
        Object startDateValue = component.getAttributes().get("fi");
        if (startDateValue==null) {
            return;
        }
         
        Date startDate = (Date)startDateValue;
        Date endDate = (Date)value; 
        
        if (endDate.before(startDate)) {    
        this.validacionFechas = false;        
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "¡Error!", "La fecha inicial no puede ser mayor a la final."));           
        }
       
    }
   
    public boolean getValidacionFechas() {
        return validacionFechas;
    }

    public void setValidacionFechas(boolean validacionFechas) {
        this.validacionFechas = validacionFechas;
    }
}
```

The validation between the dates are correct, and the message too. But from another class(where i have my Save method) i'm calling the variable this way:

```
PrimeDateRangeValidator pdrv = new PrimeDateRangeValidator();
pdrv.getValidacionFechas();
```

And i'm always getting TRUE, cousing this to save the information if the dates are correct, and when the dates are incorrect show the error message but saves the information too.

Is there any problem with the @FacesValidator or with the set and get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation can't work. You are creating a new instance of PrimeDateRangeValidator which has nothing to do with the 
validator instance that JSF creates and uses itself. I'm just wondering why getValidacionFechas always returns true. It should 
return false.

I think the best way is to put the information of the validation into the session map, for example:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("VALIDACION_FECHAS", false);
```

And read it like that:

```
boolean validacionFechas =  (boolean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("VALIDACION_FECHAS");
```